# In Swift, how can I use an alias name for the struct/class which is mapped to object returned in JSON (from WebAPI call)?

Tags: swift, mapping, codable

I am making a call to a WebAPI which returns the following JSON.
The JSON contains an object named `group` which I want to map in my Swift code using `Codable` protocol.

```
"group":{"ID":4,"OwnerId":22,"MemberId":17,"Name":"FirstGroup",
"Created":"2024-02-23","Active":1}
```

In Swift I have created the small struct so the mapping will be done.

```
struct Group: Codable{
   var id: Int64
   var OwnerId: Int64
.  
. // reset of items mapped
}
```

However, when I go to build, there is a clash between the `struct Group` I defined and the SwiftUI `Group`.

I believe I'm stuck now however, because when the mapping is done when I retrieve the JSON I know it will look for object named `Group` in my JSON to do the automatic mapping.

Is there a way to use an alias name for the Swift side but still map to the JSON's group object?

In this instance, I can't change the WebAPI to return another name.

Comment: Your struct doesn't have to be called `Group`. Call it something else. The synthesised `Codable` implementation is based on property names, not type names.

Comment: @Sweeper It will map just by recognizing the types inside the object?  It doesn't care about that outer name ("group")?

Comment: Yes, `struct Response: Codable { let group: SomeGroup ...}` will work fine.

Comment: Ok, I will try it out.  I thought I had tried that with another JSON object which failed.  But I'm a bit of a newbie so that other one may have failed for another reason.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: You can use `SwiftUI.Group` and `<AppName>.Group` to distinguish them